# Javascript - use a variable's value (directly, not by reference) when declaring an asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, variables, events

Alright so,

I have something that looks like this :

```
for (j = 0; j < btnArr.length; j++)
{
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.addEventListener("click", function() { press(this, j) }, false);
    div.appendChild(btn);
}
```

My problem is, since that the event happens at a late time, `j` has already changed value by time the event's function is triggered. I want the function to directly use `j`'s value when the function is declared, and not a reference to `j` itself.

If `addEventListener`'s 2nd parameter was a string, it would look like this:

```
btn.addEventListener("click", "function() { press(this, " + j + ") }", false);
```

Does anyone know if it's possible, and how to do this?

I tried searching around a bit, but I can't find anything relevant, since the problem is hard to describe properly with only a few words.

By the way, this is for a Greasemonkey script, hence   the use of `.addEventListener()` instead of `.onclick = (...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to break the context. It can be done a ton of ways, but [Function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) is the most elegant IMHO. Since you are in Firefox, bind should be there.

```
for (j = 0; j < btnArr.length; j++)
{
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.addEventListener("click", function(value) { press(this, value) }.bind(btn, j), false);
    div.appendChild(btn);
}
```

For an alternate approach, write a function that returns the handler.

```
for (j = 0; j < btnArr.length; j++)
{
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.addEventListener("click", getHandler(j), false);
    div.appendChild(btn);
}

function getHandler(j) {
    return function() { press(this, j) };
}
```

Yet another option is to add a property to the `button` element.

```
for (j = 0; j < btnArr.length; j++)
{
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.myValue = j;
    btn.addEventListener("click", function() { press(this, this.myValue); }, false);
    div.appendChild(btn);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the .bind mess up the `this` inside his function?

Comment: Only if you specify it. It doesn't mess with `this` if `null` is passed. I suppose `btn` could be passed there too since that is what the context will be.

Comment: On my side, it does actually mess with this, since its attributes' values all return undefined (in the original code, they are defined just after the createElement).

Comment: @AgentRev: I don't like putting stuff on the button properties that much. There is always the risk of name collision with another event handler or with an existing DOM property (specially the side-effecting ones like innerHTML)

Comment: @missingno: Which is why I rethought to it and removed that part of my comment before you replied :) Anyway, using custom names shouldn't pose any real risk in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

You have struck the age old problem of closures in listeners. You can use:

```
btn.addEventListener("click", (function(x) {
                                 return function(){
                                    press(this, x) 
                                 };
                               }(j)), false);
```

and to avoid memory leaks in some browsers, remove the reference to the element when you're finished with it:

```
btn = null;
```

to break the closure. There are many answers for this on SO. You can use *bind*, but that isn't available on all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

btn is an object and you can always add your own properties and access them later:

```
for (var j = 0; j < btnArr.length; j++)
{
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.index = j;
    btn.addEventListener("click", function() { press(this, this.index) }, false);
    div.appendChild(btn);
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/Kai/Y2KaZ/

Comment: For my case, it works and it is the simplest method. However if someone wanted to use the value in a function that doesn't access any object by default, he would have to either pass an object where the value is stored or use another approach.

Comment: Yes, this solution was for your described case; I'm glad it works. I don't quite understand your other case in the above comment -- do you have a code example?

Comment: Say, `btn.addEventListener("click", function() { press(j) }, false);`. Also, I selected Hemlock's answer as best over yours, but only because he shows multiple ways of doing it in addition to yours :)

Comment: What's wrong with `press(this.index)`? `this.index` is only a number which it gets from the context of the button.

Comment: Oh well, I guess you're right. The way I did it was to only pass `this` to `press()`, and use the `.value` inside `press()` itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the rules of lexical scope like that. What you can do is use the fact that if you create a helper function it will gladly create a new bindings for you.

```
function make_handler(i){
    //you can use j here as well instead of i
    //I'm just avoiding shadowing for didactic reasons...
    return function() { press(this, i) };
}

for (j = 0; j < btnArr.length; j++)
{
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.addEventListener("click", make_handler(j), false);
    div.appendChild(btn);
}
```